# Example on how to use seek(time, [callback]) in Flowplayer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, flowplayer

I'm trying to understand the flowplayer API, I'll be honest, I really need examples to get this stuff. I know some of you ninjas know what you're doing quite easily.

I am building a video training page for someone. It uses a PHP (kirbycms) framework to generate pages. I understand how to drop my variables and all that stuff. I have the videos working. It would be largely beneficial if I could have cue points that trigger things, and buttons that seek to specific time codes. It would be best if I can use PHP to define a string for these links.

I am looking for an example on how to use `seek(time, [callback])`

I am also looking for an example of

```
$(".player").bind("cuepoint", function(e, api, cuepoint) {
   // here we use custom properties left, top and html
   $("#info").html(cuepoint.html).animate({
      left: cuepoint.left,
      top: cuepoint.top
   });
});
```

### Update

**Included bootply,** this still does not work for me. Is it because my controls are outside of the flowplayer window?

http://bootply.com/86532

Comment: but actually what is the question? If you're looking for examples they should be in the documentation for that plugin.

Comment: THe problem is that the features i'm asking about are poorly documented and have no examples.

Comment: my problem is that I don't know jQuery and I don't know how to make this feature function as the API explains. The documentation is possibly great for advanced javascript users but is completely useless for me. I can usually get things working with the code on jquery.com but this code is incomplete and does not work when I try to use it.

Comment: so maybe you should just learn a little bit more about javascript because if you want to do websites you need to understand it and read documentation with comprehension.

Comment: thanks for the useful answer. I fail to see how a comment like:

   // here we use custom properties left, top and html
is useful documentation. Ok, now where is the documentation for their custom classes? There isn't any. Googlesearch for custom classes with those names, brings up everyone elses implimentations but nothing for the code there.

If the documentation for flowplayer exsists, please link me to it, because the "documentation" at flowplayer.org/docs is useless.

Comment: That API is certainly NOT well documented. It is a list of properties and a list of methods without specifics, and some of the methods are outdated and don't work across both Flowplayer implementations.

Answer (score 0):

`seek` function (as documentation says: [CLICK](http://flowplayer.org/docs/api.html)) is for jumping into given time on the timeline:

```
seek(time, [callback])
```

It takes two arguments: time in seconds and a callback - function that will be executed after jumping into that time on the timeline. Assuming that you are using jQuery you can write something like this to jump into 15.5s of the movie if you click button and then alert some message (just a simple example):

```
flowplayer(function (api, root) {

  $("#someButton").on('click' function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    api.seek(15.5, function(){
      alert("you've jumped to 15.5s of the movie!");
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you. this helps a lot. It was completely at a lost in how to write the javascript for these functions.

Comment: this ended up not working, i have updated my question with more information and a bootly.

Comment: is my problem because the links I want to use to control the flowplayer outside of the div that flow player lives in? how would that affect the code?

Comment: The OP is asking for a video to trigger code when the play head hits a particular cuepoint. The seek function is the opposite. It doesn't trigger code. It triggers the video to jump to that particular point in time.

Answer (score 0):

Flowplayer doesn't do what you're after. In fact, `seek()` pretty much does the opposite- it triggers the video to jump to that point in time (and optionally calls back when its done).

If you want to set cuepoints and have the video trigger code when the video reaches those points in time, have a look at `addEventListener("timeupdate", callback)`, see [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/timeupdate).

You might also want to check out [popcornjs](http://popcornjs.org/).